# Error building project from GitLab: "terminal prompts disabled"

Tags: gitlab, read-the-docs

I am starting to use Read the Docs with GitLab. I set up a project with Sphinx and hooked it up. Every time a build is triggered at RTD the following messages are displayed:

```
git clone --no-single-branch --depth 50 https://gitlab.com/ldesousa/docs-repo .
Cloning into '.'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Locally the project is building fine. I also added a [`.readthedocs.yml`](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html) file to the root of the project, but the problem prevails.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, as described in "[Documentation using Sphinx and ReadTheDocs.org](https://dont-be-afraid-to-commit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation.html)" to use an SSH URL instead:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<your git username>/my-first-docs.git
```

In your Git clone command, try and use a similar SSH URL.

Comment: The page you link to explains how to set up the development environment. If I understand your answer correctly, I must do something similar in the RTD environment. However, so far the only mechanism I found is the `requirements.txt` file. Could you please detail how to do this at RTD?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I don't have an environment for me to experiment, but the idea is: if you have specified anywhere in your current setting an HTTPS URL, try and replace it by an SSH one.

Comment: I have not specific that in any way for the build environment at RTD. Nor can I find anywhere to do it.